# Why Does ASP.net Authentication Template not include Redux with React?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, vue.js, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a new SPA project in React or Vue using netcore3.1 or net5.0.
I want to include Identity for Auth.

There are no Vue templates.
The React Template with Redux does not allow for an identity/authentication template.

Is it considered incorrect to build a SPA and utilize the identity razor page scaffolding with a vue/react SPA?

Is there a problem with adding Redux utility to the default React.js + Identity project which uses the services.AddDefaultIdentity() & Identity UI scaffolding?